# How to create a firebase cloud function that could trigger when database is read

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to have a firebase cloud function that could trigger when sone one read the realtime database.

As per this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events , We can have cloud function to trigger when data is created, updated, or deleted on Realtime Database. But i want to do some external network call if some one is reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no OnRead trigger or a way to achieve this behavior, however [Here](https://issuetracker.google.com/149876862) is a feature request on Google to support this in the future.

I recommend you to follow up over there to see any progress made on this.